# Specific aggregation of matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization

Let us consider the matrix 'x1':

```
x1 = {{1, 2, 3, m}, {4, 5, 6, n}, {7, 8, 9, o}, {10, 11, 12, o}}

MatrixForm[x1]
```

From the matrix 'x1' we compute the matrix 'x2':

```
x2 = Table[Sum[Sum[x1[[k1, k2]], {k2, 1, j}], {k1, 1, i}], {i, 1, Length[x1[[1]]]}, {j, 1, Length[x1[[All, 1]]]}]

MatrixForm[x2]
```

The problem is that the code for the calculation of 'x2' is very slow for large matrix 'x1'. How else can calculate the matrix 'x2'?

ralph

Answer (score 4):

Reference [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
x1 = {{1, 2, 3, m}, {4, 5, 6, n}, {7, 8, 9, o}, {10, 11, 12, o}};

x2 = Accumulate[Accumulate /@ x1];

x2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 6 & m+6 \\
 5 & 12 & 21 & m+n+21 \\
 12 & 27 & 45 & m+n+o+45 \\
 22 & 48 & 78 & m+n+2 o+78 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Equivalently:

```
Map[Accumulate, x1, {0, 1}]
```

Comment: nice ! we can also get rid of `Map` with `Apply` and `SlotSequence` like `Accumulate[Accumulate[{##}] & @@@ x1]`

Comment: @AliHashmi Thank you.  However I don't see why one would prefer `Apply` here as it makes the code more complicated rather than simpler, and it will unpack packed arrays.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks forgot about unpacking of packed arrays. Btw, does it mean that `Map` will not unpack a packed array?

Comment: @Ali It should not, but of course the function that is mapped will unpack if it cannot handle a packed array.  You can evaluate `On["Packing"]` and see for yourself (watch for messages).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i just saw your second solution now. Its very elegant. +1 !